# Change shape of nparray

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
​
image1 = np.zeros((120, 120))
image2 = np.zeros((120, 120))
image3 = np.zeros((120, 120))
​
pack1 = np.array([image1,image2,image3])
pack2 = np.array([image1,image2,image3])
​
result = np.array([pack1,pack2])

print result.shape
```

the result is : 
(2, 3, 120, 120)

Question : how can I make array with shape (2,120,120,3) with same data without mixing?

Comment: Look into `swapaxes`, `transpose`, `rollaxis`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.rollaxis` to move (OK, roll) a single axis to a specified position:

```
>>> a.shape
(2, 3, 11, 11)
>>> np.rollaxis(a, 0, 4).shape
(3, 11, 11, 2)
```

Here the syntax is "roll the zeroth axis so that it becomes the 4th in the new array".

Notice that `rollaxis` creates a view and does not copy:

```
>>> np.rollaxis(a, 0, 4).base is a
True
```

An alternative (and often more readable) way would be to use the fact that `np.transpose` accepts a tuple of where to place the axes. Observe:

```
>>> np.transpose(a, (1, 2, 3, 0)).shape
(3, 11, 11, 2)
>>> np.transpose(a, (1, 2, 3, 0)).base is a
True
```

Here the syntax is "permute the axes so that what was the zeroth axis in the original array becomes the 4th axis in the new array"

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose your `packs`

```
pack1 = np.array([image1,image2,image3]).T
pack2 = np.array([image1,image2,image3]).T
```

and the result has your desired shape.

Answer (score 1):

The (relatively) new `stack` function gives more control that `np.array` on how arrays are joined.

Use `stack` to join them on a new last axis:

```
In [24]: pack1=np.stack((image1,image2,image3),axis=2)
In [25]: pack1.shape
Out[25]: (120, 120, 3)
In [26]: pack2=np.stack((image1,image2,image3),axis=2)
```

then join on a new first axis (same as `np.array()`):

```
In [27]: result=np.stack((pack1,pack2),axis=0)
In [28]: result.shape
Out[28]: (2, 120, 120, 3)
```