# Rearranging a 4d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 4d numpy array which represents a dataset with 3d instances.
Lets say that the shape of the array is `(32, 32, 3, 73257)`.

How can i change the shape of the array to `(73257, 32, 32, 3)`?

--- Question update
It seems that both rollaxis and transpose do the trick.

Thanx for replying!

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022182/change-shape-of-nparray

Comment: `transpose` would work here too if you used `(3, 0, 1, 2)`

Comment: You are right. I will correct my reply asap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `np.transpose` function does exactly what you want, you can pass an axis argument which controls which axis you want to swap:

```
a = np.empty((32, 32, 3, 73257))
b = np.transpose(a, (3, 0, 1, 2))
```

The axis of b are permuted versions of the ones of a: the axis 0 of b is the 3-rd axis of a, the axis 1 of b is the 0-th axis of a, etc...

That way, you can specify which of the axis of size 32 you want in second or in third place:

```
b = np.transpose(a, (3, 1, 0, 2))
```

Also gives an array of the desired shape, but is different from the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `np.rollaxis(arr, axis=-1)` will do what you want. Example:

```
>>> arr = np.empty(32, 32, 3, 73257)
>>> arr2 = np.rollaxis(arr, axis=-1)
>>> arr2.shape
(73257, 32, 32, 3)
```

This will make `arr[i,j,k,l] == arr2[l,i,j,k]` for all `ijkl`