# transpose on 4-d array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have a 4d array (python) with a batch of 10000 images with 5 channels in each image. Each image is 25*25 i.e. the 4d array shape is 10000*5*25*25.

I need to transpose the images. The naive way is with nested loops:

```
            for i in range(np.shape(img)[0]):
                for j in range(np.shape(img)[1]):
                    img[i, j, :, :] = np.transpose(img[i, j, :, :])
```

but I'm sure that there is a more efficient way to do this. Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: It's `np.transpose(img, [0, 1, 3, 2])`. I'm sure this has been asked here before, though :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't find a similar question.

Comment: hmm.. I could only find this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41038976/3005167 but I have to admit it was a bit hard to find...

Comment: As a further information: `img[i ,j ,: ,: ]` is equivalent to `img[i ,j ]`, so you can save some indeces, which is probalby going to improve the readability of your code

Answer (score 7):

The function [`numpy.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) is general enough to handle multi-dimensional arrays. By default it reverses the order of dimensions.

However, it takes an optional `axis` argument, which explicitly specifies the order in which to rearrange the dimensions. To swap the last two dimensions in a 4D array (i.e. transposing a stack of images):

```
np.transpose(x, [0, 1, 3, 2])
```

No loops are required, it simply works on the entire 4D array and is super efficient.

Some more examples:

```
np.transpose(x, [0, 1, 2, 3])  # leaves the array unchanged
np.transpose(x, [3, 2, 1, 0])  # same as np.transpose(x)
np.transpose(x, [0, 2, 1, 3])  # transpose a stack of images with channel in the last dim
```

Comment: Looks like there is no canonical answer to this type of question, yet. Or at least I could not find one easily. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Could also do `np.swapaxes(x, 2, 3)` to be a little more readable in this case.

Comment: Yep, that's right. Personally, I prefer to use `transpose` in most cases.

Comment: The function documentation has a 3d example.